# How do I look up something in a dictionary with a variable in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

My program receives an input from the user and I want to use this value as a key to look up something in a dictionary. I haven't found anything online that could help me with this problem.

```
transports = {'11': 'car', '12': 'bus', '13':'train'} 
number = int(input("Enter either 11, 12 or 13")) 
transportType = transports.get(number) 
print(transportType)
```

Comment: `if your_input in your_dictionary: ...`

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain what problem you met exactly...

Comment: transports = {'11': 'car', '12': 'bus', '13':'train'}
number = int(input("Enter either 11, 12 or 13"))
transportType = transports.get(number)
print(transportType)

Comment: 'None' is printed

Comment: Your keys are strings, but you try to find a key with an integer value.

Comment: In other words: drop the call to `int`, use `number = input("Enter either 11, 12 or 13")` and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the input in a variable and then check whether that input is in the key listing of the dictionary. See example below:

```
mydict = {'first':1, 'second':2}

mykey = input('Give me a key!')


if mykey in mydict.keys():
    print(mydict[mykey])
else:
    print('your input not in mydict')
```